# how to determine how many lp locked tokens were burned

Tags: web3.js, token, dex, raydium, burn

so I have the addresses of the new token.
I also have the address of the raydium pool.

How do I determine how many lp tokens have been burned?

I want to do something similar to that functionality from rugcheck xyz

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out the amount of burned tokens, you'll need to crawl through all transactions involving the mint address and look for burn instructions in the top-level or inner instructions.